# Lazy ssh key prompt for command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, ssh-keys

My question is (very) similar to [lazy prompt for ssh public key passphrase](https://superuser.com/questions/551914/lazy-prompt-for-ssh-public-key-passphrase) but the answer provided there (using GNOME keyring) doesn't really fit the bill (I'd rather have no reliance on X or any other graphical environment).

I'm looking for a solution that loads your SSH key in a lazy way, meaning that it only asks for a passphrase when the key is actually needed so it doesn't get in the way when you don't need it.

Are there any commandline solutions out there or some hooks I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ssh-agent? I think its one worth looking into, you just need to switch to using public key authentication and run agent on computer your connecting to elsewhere.

Other is using keychain, explained in: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/

But its recommended only for scripting purposes. Passwords are there to improve security, incase your account gets compromised.

Comment: There is also keychain to use with SSH publickeys: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/

Comment: I've been using ssh-agent and keychain for a while, my problem is in adding the key to the agent/keychain. 

Right now this happens when I first log in but I'd rather not have it ask for my passphrase until the first use of the key (as GNOME keyring does)